# Not able to connect Android Phone to Macbook pro

Tags: android-studio

Environment 
Android Phone: Samsung Galaxy S2.
Macbook Pro 
Operating System: OS X El Capitan
Problem:
Phone could not be detected by mac or android studio.
What I did:
Tried connecting with different cables.
Enabled Developer Options and USB debugging.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid this is not on topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Pekka웃 correct. If the PC detects it but AS doesn't, then it would be. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, a Samsung Galaxy S3, and Mac OSX El Capitan.

I had to download and install the Samsung Mac OSX suite. This suite is called "Kies". After installation, you will find a menu item that installs the needed drivers on the Mac side. Additionally, you need to install protocols on your phone in order to be able to connect to the Mac, and for this, you will need an app from the app store that installs the necessary MTP drivers (do this before you connect your phone to the Mac).

Regards,

Comment: Can you provide images and re-format your paragraph to make it look neater by seperating them?

Comment: @Ukimiku I can not see any kies for mac. Although for mac is provided on samsung website but when we download it turns out to be .exe.

Comment: Look and download from here: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/   On the website the first download link is for Windows (.exe). Scroll down. There is the Mac version.